# I need to show all items except todays

Tags: mysql

SHow me where and what to add code for below query

```
$randitems = $DB->getAll("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "items` a WHERE `enabled`=1 AND `visible`=1 $filter order by RAND() limit 7");
$smarty->assign("randitems", $randitems);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `date` column in your `items` table, just add `AND DATE(date_column) < DATE(NOW())` to your WHERE clause.